# Mandatory options with getopt_long() in C

Tags: c, getopt-long

With C/ C++, `getopt_long()` can be used to parse command line arguments. Is it possible to tell the function that some of the options are mandatory? For example, how can I tell `getopt_long` that the parsing should give error if `startServer` is called without mentioning the port below?

`./startServer -port 80`

Note: I am not talking of option arguments as mandatory but rather the options themselves.

Comment: i doubt there's a way. keep track of whether that option has been seen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getopt_long()` is not part of the C language.  It is a GNU invention which is available in some C implementations, but far from all.

The version of `getopt_long()` in glibc (used in most Linux distributions) does not allow you to specify that an option is mandatory.  You'll have to check them explicitly after you're done parsing the command line.